# Using the has pseudo selector with a class as an argument?

Tags: html, css

Should this turn the nav red?

```css
nav:has(.HasThis) {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Here's a demo.

```css
nav:has(.HasThis) {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="HasThis">
    <a href="/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
    <a href="/page2.html">Other page</a>
</nav>
```

For example this will turn it red.

```css
nav.HasThis {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

And I was wondering whether:

```css
nav:has(.HasThis) {
  background-color: red !important;
}
```

Should achieve the same thing?

Comment: No thats not how to use`has` . Aren't you looking for `nav.HasThis` ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @0stone0 yes I've used the type of select `nav.HasThis` in the past ... But I was wondering whether this would achieve the same effect ...

Comment: No but instead of `:has` you could use `:is` but frankly it's redundant since a simple class selector works fine. https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/QWPqWjO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should this turn the nav red?

No, when reading the [MDN web docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has);

> The functional `:has()` CSS [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes) represents an element if any of the [relative selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Selector_structure#relative_selector) that are passed as an argument match at least one element when anchored against this element.
>
> This pseudo-class presents a way of selecting a parent element or a previous sibling element with respect to a reference element by taking a [relative selector list](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Selector_list#relative_selector_list) as an argument.

So the `nav` doesn't have a `HasThis` **anchored against this element**.

---

If you want to target all the `nav`'s that have a class `HasThis`, use:

```
nav.HasThis
```

```css
nav.HasThis {
    background-color: red !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="HasThis">
    <a href="/" aria-current="page">Home</a>
    <a href="/page2.html">Other page</a>
</nav>
```